# Display a relation on openstreetmap

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm working on a project and I'm using osmdroid and osmbonuspack (for an android app). I would like to display a relation that I previously get from osm. I have the osm data in a string. I've tried to get all the node points of the relation and draw the route with the roadManager of osmbonuspack (like in the Tutorial 1), but the relation doesn't look right.
I hope I you can help me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: We cannot really help with this level of information. Which kind of data do you have? What "doesn't look right" exactly? The roadManager needs a Road object, which is a complex structure. If you just have a list of points, use the osmdroid PathOverlay or osmbonuspack Polyline.

Comment: Sorry @MKer, my English is not very good. I'll try to explain it better. I have an array where I've got all the geopoints that I get from the osm file.When I draw this relation with the PathOverlay, it looks like the order of the nodes it's not correct. So instead of having the relationship as it should, I have a lot of lines that intersect between them.

Comment: PathOverlay displays the geopoints exactly in the order of their addition. There is something wrong somewhere - either in your code, or in the data source from which you get your list of points. Could you provide relevant parts of your code?